# How to enable bottle to search multiple paths for rendering templates?

Tags: python, html, templates, bottle

I am trying to find a way to have multiple paths searched for rendering templates, not only the `/views` directory. I want to keep my base and page templates separate from my includes, such as my head, header, and footer. I want to nest an `/includes` directory inside my `/views` directory that bottle searches when rendering templates. I tried playing around with `TEMPLATE_PATHS` but I could not get it to work. Could someone please point me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH` list variable appending to it any other paths where you want Bottle to look for templates. See the [docs](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#tutorial-templates).

For example:

```
from bottle import route, run, template, TEMPLATE_PATH

TEMPLATE_PATH.append('./other_templates')


@route('/hello')
@route('/hello/<name>')
def hello(name='World'):
    return template('hello_template', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Where my files are structured like this:

```
.
├── other_templates
│   └── hello_template.tpl
└── server.py
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @zack-stone Glad it helped! Can we mark this as the right answer then?